# 2701hg-b outbound port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

So I forwarded port 22 on my 2701hg-b ADSL modem to one of my machines and set a hostname for the public IP. From the outside, I can SSH access using either public IP or host name without any problems. From inside the network, I can't use either public IP or host name to access my own network.

Any clues what this could be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most ISPs or routers (I can't remember which) doesn't allow you to connect to itself from inside the network.  You can't be on the local network, go to the ISP and have that pack return back to the original address.

If you want to SSH inside the local network you will need to use the IP address of the machine the port is forwarded to.

Answer (score 0):

On some routers it is possible to set an internal hostname. This same issue can be resolved by editing the hosts file on your computer to set the hostname you want to the IP address of the router.